# Cannot find own outgoing Hangouts chat messages in history via Gmail search

Tags: gmail, search, google-hangouts

I have failed to find any of my very own outgoing Hangouts chat messages in history via Gmail search, whereas the search finds any of Hangouts chat messages of another participant of the very same Hangouts chat.

What can it be and how can I fix it?